# Erlang Wx : how to add new widgets

Tags: html, erlang, wxwidgets, wxerlang

Erlang comes with a very nice binding of Wx library.
I would like to know if someone has ever tried to add new widgets (on linux or windows) to the wx library originally installed with Erlang (v. R15) ?

I explain: It would be nice if, using an excellent control such as wxWebConnect, we can insert HTML5 support into Erlang. The idea is to use Javascript for a part of my GUI. WxErlang offers a control called wxHTMLWindow but no support for HTML5 and javascript. wxWebConnect does it perfectly.

By having a look at the Erlang source code that implements the Wx binding (Erlang source code using a wx library compiled as a DLL on windows), there are many files that seem to have been generated automatically using a Ericson tool (I assume to convert C .h files into their equivalent in Erlang).

If all this is clear for someone (sorry for my poor explanation) please give me any information that can help to go further in adding new widgets to wxErlang (my first target is wxWebConnect).

B. Lamine

Answer (score 4):

All of the wx API's are generated using the files in https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/master/lib/wx/api_gen. So if you want to add support for something new you should look in there.

Comment: Thank you! As soon as I get something with wxWebConnect on WxErlang, I will let you know !